# Commiting to BitBucket via the command line

Tags: git, bash, bitbucket

I'm trying to set up a new project with BitBucket, and make a commit to it using the command line...

So, I have logged in to the BitBucket website with my username "karnivaurus", and created a new project called "foo". I have an existing directory at "/c/bar" containing a number of files, which I want to start using with git. Following the instructions at the BitBucket website, from the command line (using Git Bash), I typed in:

```
cd /c/bar
git init
git remote add origin https://karnivaurus@bitbucket.org/karnivaurus/foo.git
```

Then, I add all the files with:

```
git add .
```

And finally commit with:

```
git commit -m "First commit."
```

This seems to be ok, with a number of messages output listing the files in the directory, e.g. "create mode 100644 myfile.txt". However, when I then go back to the BitBucket website, under the "Sources" tab it says "The source directory is empty.", and under the "Commits" tab it says "I have no commits".

I have tried refreshing and logging back in again, but I still see no files or commits.

Why have these commits not been made to the BitBucket project?

Comment: `git commit` commits the files locally. You need to push those changes to the remote you set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git commit -m "First commit."
```

This command doing commit only to your local repository (on your file system)

To sync branch of your local repository with remote one (bitbucket in your case) you need to call:

```
git push origin <branch name>
```

(branch name is 'master' by default)

Answer (score 6):

You need to `git push origin branch-name` to push your commits to remote. Only then can you see your commits on bitbucket. Try `git help push` for reference

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the four-word version of `git push` is only necessary the first time for a new branch and that the setting of `push.default` should be set in versions of git older than 2.0.

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner for that info.